# C# - Dynamically generated classes?

Tags: c#, class, dynamic

I am in need of creating a dynamically extend-able class in C#.
The goal is to create a class what can contain all info from a given contact from an Android SQLite Contacts table. The table's structure is kinda weird, as it does not have set field names, but uses colums of 'field name' and 'field content'.

That's what I want to turn into a usable format where the code reads the database, and for each entry creates the matching sub-variable. Such I want to know the best method to do so (I guess a simple

```
{
    this.(variableNames[i].ToString()) = variableContent[i];
}
```

will not do it), what is the least resource-eating, but fastest (and easiest) way.

And also if we are here, is there ANY method to call a type's (let's say, I create a new Contact with e-mail, workplace, name, and image tags, but these variables names' are unknown) ALL sub-variables (Contact.image, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, etc) dynamically?

Of course there will be standardized fields what should be in ALL contact (one of the three names, phone number, e-mail @work and @home, and such), but these should be called dynamically too.

Comment: How about implementing a collection/list/dictionary of some sort, generics will give you the nice strong-typedness you need for it to be manageable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`Dictionary<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead.

```
Dictionary<string,string> contactInfo = new Dictionary<string,string>();

public void ImportContact()
{
    ...
    // for each fieldName and fieldValue from your table
    contactInfo.Add(fieldName, fieldValue);
    ...
    // check that all standard fields are present, if desired
}

public string FirstName
{
    get { return contactInfo["FirstName"]; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go with dynamic typing, you can use the `dynamic` type in C# 4. You can use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) as a base for your Contact types.

Here is an example of a Contact class that can work both statically typed with some pre-defined properties; and can have properties attached to it at run-time. When treating it statically, you can still get the values by using the indexer:

```
class Contact : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, object> bag = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return bag[key]; }
        set { bag[key] = value; }
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (bag.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = bag[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        bag[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
    // Contact is statically typed.
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.FirstName = "test";       

    // Treat as dynamic and attach some extra properties:
    dynamic dynContact = c;
    dynContact.AddressOne = "Somewhere";
    dynContact.AddressTwo = "Someplace else";
    Console.WriteLine(dynContact.AddressOne); 
    Console.WriteLine(dynContact.AddressTwo);
```

Other than using `dynamic`, you cannot create a new class with dynamically typed properties. After all, how would you consume those properties ? You might be better off creating a class containing the properties that you must have; and put the rest in a `Dictionary<string,object>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.0, there's dynamic support. You can create objects something like this:

```
var newContact = new object { FirstName = "name", LastName = "name", etc... };
```

Alternatively, you might want to try using a Dictionary.